# Image cannot be uploaded

Tags: python, django

Image cannot be uploaded.form.is_valid() always returned Flase.I wrote in html

```
<main>
    <form action="/app/img/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Upload Image!!</h3>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn-lg">
                    Select image
                    <input id="file1" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
            <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

in views.py

```
@require_POST
def img(request):
    img_form = ImageForm(request.POST or None)
    print(img_form.is_valid())
    if request.method == "POST" and img_form.is_valid():
        image = request.POST.get("image", "")
```

in forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image',)
```

I really cannot understand why I can't sent images.form.is_valid() returned Flase means Form cannot be gotten images, right? What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads):

> When Django handles a file upload, the file data ends up placed in `request.FILES`.

You are not passing `request.FILES` to your form, so it never sees the uploaded file. You need to pass this to the form as follows:

```
img_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```